# Can you say “I savaged myself” or “She savaged herself” for something or someone?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, idiomatic-language

Can you say “I savaged myself” or “He/She savaged himself/herself” for something or someone? For instance, someone was trying to prepare themselves for a contest or a competition, fiercely changing their appearance, behavior etc. and now they are not too happy about it. So is it O’K if this person would use a word “Savage” as a verb for a more dramatic effect (in an interview for example) and say that they savaged themselves for a chance to be on the show?
Thank you!

Comment: Many people tend to avoid 'savage' to mean "violently attack", these days, because of the racist use of the word when applied to indigenous peoples. Also, I don't think it quite fits the meaning you are looking for.

Comment: I'd never have thought of "racist" overtones (it seems a bit of a stretch to me), but I don't think reflexive ***to savage oneself*** is a very "natural" usage. Having said that, [***he savaged himself***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+savaged+himself%22) has occurred in print several times. I don't recommend it though.

Comment: ...this is off-topic "creative writing advice", but you could use something more colloquially idiomatic, such as *He [**put himself through the wringer**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22put+himself+through+the+wringer%22) to be on the show*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how Merriam-Webster defines the verb [*savage*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/savage):

> : to attack or treat brutally

If I mutilate myself with a knife, then it would make sense to say *I savaged myself*. In fact, I'd argue it would be a natural phrase in that context. It's at least one that I've heard applied in such a context before. The reflexive use is also fine in that context.

But simply changing your appearance doesn't have the same sense of permanent harm or attack that *savaged* would imply. Hearing the verb applied to makeup or clothing would be out of place.

---

Even if they are trying to use a verb in a dramatically figurative fashion, I think *savaged* would be taking it a little too far. You likely wouldn't say *I brutalized myself* or *I abused myself* in this context either.

It's possible you could use *attack*, if you qualified it: *I attacked myself* ***with new clothing and makeup.*** If said in the right way, it would convey a mix of imagery and humour.

Otherwise, something more simple like *I transfigured myself* would be dramatic enough, without also having an implication of harm.

---

In response to a comment:

> changing the appearance in this context implies plastic surgery

In that specific context, the use of *savaged* might be appropriate—although normally only if the results were undesirable and harmful.

Also, unless you performed the surgery on yourself, the specific phrasing would be *I was savaged* or *I got myself savaged*.

Comment: Thank you very much! And so sorry I did not clarify it in my first post, but changing the appearance in this context implies plastic surgery. So, I guess, since it is a permanent harm, the word "savaged" could be used in this context, right? Thank you, again!

Comment: @Scarlett Ah! Yes. Especially if the plastic surgery produced *harmful* or *undesirable* effects. However, unless you performed the surgery on yourself, you would say *I was savaged* or *I got myself savaged*. I have updated my answer to include this.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much, Jason!